# not rounding tofixed

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the first decimals of a float number without any kind of rounding.

Example:

```
var myfloat = 1.1864526;
myfloat = myfloat.toFixed(2);
```

It returns `1.19` but I need `1.18`.

I'm pretty sure there is an easy solution but I am unable to find it without converting the number to a string (not useful in this case).

Comment: How about parseInt(value * 100)/100 ?

Comment: you can simply give it as `.toFixed(3).slice(0, -1)`

Comment: @AswinRamesh, no, it would round up with `.9999` values.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the float value by 100, get the int value of the result then divide that int by 100. Something like this should work:

((int)(myFloat*100)) / 100